# Drop column of pd dataframe if one specific entry is 0

Tags: python, dataframe, drop

I'm trying to drop columns from a df in which one spec. entry is 0. So in the pic I wont to drop Loan F to Loan P cause the entries in row zero is 0. Can anyone help here? Thx!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, iterate through each column, see if the first row (assume that is where you are looking for the zero) value is equal to 0 and delete that column if true.

```
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].iloc[0] == 0:
        df.drop(col, axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thx! Due to possible changes to the df before read into python, this works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

To check if a column contains a particular value, you'll want to use `df.any()`:

```py
(df['Loan F'] == 0).any()
True
```

Next, just loop this condition through all of your columns:

```py
columns = [c for c in df.columns if (df[c] == 0).any()]
```

And then drop those

```py
df = df.drop(columns)
```